# UITextField Placeholder With Vibrancy

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

Is it possible to add vibrancy (UIVibrancyEffect) to a textfield's placeholder?

I have setup a table view with its separators with vibrancy (tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect) and I think the textfield's placeholders would look really good with vibrancy too.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question,

this is the way to add Vibrancy Effect :

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVibrancyEffect *vibrance = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrance];

visualEffectView.frame = textfield.bounds;
[textfield addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

More information here ([UIVibrancy Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html))

Hope this can help you ;)

Comment: No deal, this doesn't change the layout and removes touches from the textfield same as if it would have `userInteractionEnabled = NO`. I tried finding out if UITextFields have any subviews that might contain the placeholder, but I had no luck